# WebKit and its legacy prefixes

Tags: javascript, css, webkit, vendor-prefix

I am trying to compile the **properties** prefixed by `-apple-` and `-khtml-` which are/were supported by WebKit *and* since **which version** they were eventually dropped or introduced.
What are the limitations imposed on them? For example can you find them in `document.body.style`?

I guess only someone in the know like the reporter of [this bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=83256) could provide us an accurate list.
But I prefer asking here first this way everyone will benefit from it…

A good place to start your investigation is [this revision](http://trac.webkit.org/changeset/64071).

Comment: I think you mean `-webkit-` and not `-khtml-`

Comment: @pointy nop I mean `-khtml-`.

Comment: Oh - so you mean like *really* old prefixes.

Comment: *"For example can you find them in `document.body.style`?"* A quick glance at Chrome's Dev Tools says that there are **no** `-apple-` or `-khtml-` prefixed properties in the computed style of an element. That doesn't mean that ones found in CSS files aren't mapped to something up-to-date...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Introduction

The problem is not quite as simple as you might think. It is easy enough to compare revisions of the "official" list of supported CSS properties and determine the revisions at which they were introduced or retired; however, support for the *use* of legacy prefixes is also determined by how they are handled by the CSS parser implementation. Thus, you should consult both the timeline and the full list of legacy prefixed properties below to determine how support is handled in a given WebKit revision.

### Timeline of parser changes relating to legacy property support

- [5 May 2003 (r9101)](http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/WebCore/khtml/css/parser.y?rev=9101): `-apple` (and briefly `-moz`!) will be normalized to `-khtml` behind the scenes.
- [30 Aug 2005 (r10397)](http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/WebCore/khtml/css/parser.y?rev=10397): `-webkit` added as an alternative to `-khtml`.
- [14 Jun 2006 (r13874)](http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/WebCore/css/CSSGrammar.y?rev=13874): **all `-webkit`
  properties** will work with legacy prefixes (i.e. `-apple` and `-khtml` are normalized to `-webkit`). All remaining legacy prefixes were updated to `-webkit` in this revision.
- [19 Feb 2008 (r30393)](http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/WebCore/css/CSSParser.cpp?rev=30393): legacy prefix handling moved from `CSSGrammar.y` to `CSSParser.cpp`.
- [21 Jul 2010 (r63854)](http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/WebCore/css/CSSParser.cpp?rev=63854): **no** legacy prefixes
  are supported except for `-apple-dashboard-region` and
  `-apple-line-clamp`.
- [26 Jul 2010 (r64071)](http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/WebCore/css/CSSParser.cpp?rev=64071): **all `-webkit`
  properties** work with legacy prefixes again. (Previous change
  reverted.)
- [10 Apr 2012 (r113795)](http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WebCore/css/CSSParser.cpp?rev=113795): **no** legacy prefixes
  are supported unless specifically enabled.

### List of legacy properties and revisions introduced/retired

The list below has been gathered from the [commit history for the list of supported properties](http://trac.webkit.org/log/trunk/Source/WebCore/css/CSSPropertyNames.in?action=follow_copy&mode=follow_copy&rev=&stop_rev=&limit=500). The first number is the revision in which support for this property was added to the list; the second is the revision in which it was removed. No distinction is made between a property being renamed as opposed to being dropped outright.

The properties removed in [r13874](http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/WebCore/css/CSSPropertyNames.in?rev=13874) lived on for some time under the `-webkit` prefix, so the legacy prefixes might continue to work depending upon how they are handled by the parser. (See the timeline above for more details.)

- **-apple-dashboard-region:** r7588 to r9101
- **-apple-line-clamp:** r6391 to r9101
- **-apple-text-size-adjust:** r6805 to r9101
- **-khtml-appearance:** r9828 to r13874
- **-khtml-binding:** r5967 to r13874
- **-khtml-border-horizontal-spacing:** r5212 to r13874
- **-khtml-border-vertical-spacing:** r5212 to r13874
- **-khtml-box-align:** r4704 to r13874
- **-khtml-box-direction:** r4704 to r13874
- **-khtml-box-flex:** r4704 to r13874
- **-khtml-box-flex-group:** r4704 to r13874
- **-khtml-box-flex-group-transition:** r6758 to r6802
- **-khtml-box-lines:** r4704 to r13874
- **-khtml-box-ordinal-group:** r4704 to r13874
- **-khtml-box-orient:** r4704 to r13874
- **-khtml-box-pack:** r4704 to r13874
- **-khtml-dashboard-region:** r9101 to r13874
- **-khtml-flow-mode:** r4704 to r8041
- **-khtml-font-size-delta:** r8382 to r13874
- **-khtml-horizontal-border-spacing:** r5200 to r5212
- **-khtml-line-break:** r7763 to r13874
- **-khtml-line-clamp:** r9101 to r13874
- **-khtml-margin-bottom-collapse:** r7362 to r13874
- **-khtml-margin-collapse:** r7362 to r13874
- **-khtml-margin-start:** r7708 to r13874
- **-khtml-margin-top-collapse:** r7362 to r13874
- **-khtml-marquee:** r5301 to r13874
- **-khtml-marquee-direction:** r5301 to r13874
- **-khtml-marquee-increment:** r5301 to r13874
- **-khtml-marquee-repetition:** r5301 to r13874
- **-khtml-marquee-speed:** r5301 to r13874
- **-khtml-marquee-style:** r5301 to r13874
- **-khtml-match-nearest-mail-blockquote-color:** r8642 to r13874
- **-khtml-nbsp-mode:** r7763 to r13874
- **-khtml-opacity:** r4704 to r5340 *****
- **-khtml-padding-start:** r7708 to r13874
- **-khtml-rtl-ordering:** r12027 to r13874
- **-khtml-text-decorations-in-effect:** r8466 to r13874
- **-khtml-text-size-adjust:** r9101 to r13874
- **-khtml-user-drag:** r6728 to r13874
- **-khtml-user-modify:** r5970 to r13874
- **-khtml-user-select:** r6728 to r13874
- **-khtml-vertical-border-spacing:** r5200 to r5212

***** Although deprecated, `-khtml-opacity`—and later `-webkit-opacity`—was honoured by the parser right up until CSSProperties.in introduced support for aliases in [r85212](http://trac.webkit.org/changeset/85212), and remains available as `-webkit-opacity` to the latest revision.

A couple of `-konq` prefixed properties were supported in very early revisions:

- **-konq-flow-mode:** r4 to r4704
- **-konq-js-clip:** r798 to r3695

### The story today

Since r13874, the WebKit CSS parser simply normalized any legacy prefixes to `-webkit`. Essentially, all `-webkit` prefixed properties worked with the `-apple` or `-khtml` prefixes:

```cpp
// If the prefix is -apple- or -khtml-, change it to -webkit-.
// This makes the string one character longer.
if (hasPrefix(buffer, length, "-apple-") || hasPrefix(buffer, length, "-khtml-")) {
    memmove(buffer + 7, buffer + 6, length + 1 - 6);
    memcpy(buffer, "-webkit", 7);
    ++length;
}
```

(This also explains why you cannot iterate through these properties in `document.body.style`—those properties have been replaced by the parser with the corresponding `-webkit` property.)

Peter Beverloo suggested that support for these properties should be [removed or phased out](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=42093) For a brief time [all legacy properties were disabled](http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/WebCore/css/CSSParser.cpp?rev=63854), with the exception of `-apple-dashboard-region` and `-apple-line-clamp`, but this was [reverted mere days later](http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/WebCore/css/CSSParser.cpp?rev=64071) because of myriad compatibility issues. In [newer revisions](http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WebCore/css/CSSParser.cpp?rev=113795), the legacy `-apple` and `-khtml` prefixes are [disabled unless built with `ENABLE(LEGACY_CSS_VENDOR_PREFIXES)`](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=83256). When this feature flag is enabled, the parser permits the older behaviour outlined above.

Comment: As you can see in my question I linked that bug, it doesn't tell me which of these properties have that "ENABLE(LEGACY_CSS_VENDOR_PREFIXES)" set, and since when their legacy variants were supported.

Comment: @Knu Ha, I hadn't realised that was a link to the bug report; I guessed it would be his website from the text. :) The best resource for getting information on what the legacy properties are is the documentation page linked in the first paragraph of my answer; but if you read on, in newer versions of WebKit _all_ legacy prefixes just get changed to `-webkit` regardless of whether they were ever valid. I'll try to clarify this.

Comment: So to be clear to get the bounty you need to compile a list of the supported `-apple-` and `-khtml-` properties and since which version of WebKit they were supported and dropped. Thanks for the effort but here you are just explaining the bug I linked already.

Comment: @Knu Three points: 1. I have updated my answer A LOT; 2. the support story is not as simple as "a list" due to prefix normalization (see above); and 3. your link to the WebKit bug tracker *really* looks like it goes to Adam Barth's home page/Twitter or something, you might want to change the link text so people know where it actually leads. :)

Comment: Ill do that. In the meantime Ill review your answer. The part about `-moz-` is really interesting.

Comment: @Knu Isn't it just? http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/WebCore/khtml/css/parser.y?rev=9101#L99 to be exact. It was removed pretty soon, fortunately, but it's an interesting nugget considering the vendor prefix uproar earlier this year!

Comment: I think I will award you the bounty just for that piece of information. BTW that doesn't mean you should stop adding information to your answer: for example [a lot](http://peter.sh/experiments/vendor-prefixed-css-property-overview/) of properties are missing from your list. You will get the tick if you manage to list them all :)

Comment: @Knu Are you referring to [the `-webkit` properties](http://peter.sh/experiments/vendor-prefixed-css-properties-webkit/) being accessible using `-apple` or `-khtml`? I decided not to attempt to list those because they're not legacy properties; rather, the parser is silently normalizing the prefixes to `-webkit` behind the scenes. The properties are still officially `-webkit` properties, not legacy prefixed properties.

Comment: @Knu E.g. [Safari 5.1.5 lets you use `-khtml-animation`](http://dabblet.com/gist/3226945) instead of `-webkit-animation`, although that has never been a legitimate thing to do, ever. :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15008/discussion-between-jordan-gray-and-knu)

Answer (score -1):

```
if("WebkitAppearance" in document.body.style) {}
if("KhtmlAppearance" in document.body.style) {}
if("MozAppearance" in document.body.style) {}
```