# Safe feature-based browser detection

Tags: javascript, browser-detection

I have been doing a bit of research on safe and reliable browser detection. Given the fact that parsing `navigator.userAgent` is the worst way to do so, since it can be easily spoofed by a user, th best bet seems to be using feature-detection. So, based on various articles in StackOveflow and elsewhere, this is what it looks like finally:

```
IE: /*@cc_on!@*/false
Firefox: -moz-box-sizing
Safari: window.getComputedStyle && !window.globalStorage && !window.opera
Opera: window.opera && window.opera.version
Chrome: window.chrome
```

Given that these will be maintained and monitored for future release of browsers (when one might disable a feature we are now using to detect it, or may be some other browser may implement it, thus the test will return true for that browser also), are there any caveats in this methods? Can the user, in any way, do stuff so that even these will return wrong results?

Comment: IE detection can be done with `<!--[if IE]>true<![endif]-->`

Comment: Did you tried http://modernizr.com/?

Comment: Detect features, not browsers.

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't address my issues. Certain features are present in say Opera, but not in the way like other browsers. So feature detection won't work (since it is there, only it needs a different implementation) in such cases..

Comment: Detect feature, if exists but known to have different implementations, do a basic implementation test, store in `localStorage`, now you know until user clears _Storage_. -- If one browser has implemented something differently, you can't trust it not to conform in future.

Comment: Yeah, I am doing that. For example, there are some anomalies with the `paste` event in Opera below V12. The event is there all right, but correctly in Opera 12 onwards, and a bit differently in Opera 9-11. So I can't do a feature detection here, since `paste` is supported by all from 9 to 12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> are there any caveats in *these* methods? Can the user, in any way, do stuff so that even these will return wrong results?

AFAIK you have to take into account two things. First an ID, depending on the browser, could [pollute the global scope](https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=11960). Secondly you can't, [already](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11759353/248058), trust the prefixes to be browser specific [anymore](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/opera-mobile-emulator-experimental-webkit-prefix-support/). I would recommend, as others users pointed out in comments, to rely on feature detection instead (what you are doing is correlated inference).

As a side note, your Safari filter is not reliable.

Comment: I didn't quite get you. What I am doing *is* feature detection, right?

Comment: @Cupidvogel You are inferring a certain browser based on features. Conventionally  *feature detection* means that you are checking the features for themselves.

Comment: Okay. But this is needed, for different browsers may implement the same feature differently..So featured detection won't help..

Comment: @Cupidvogel As a last resort only then. Did I answer your questions?